# Oracle: how to find out how much space (on RAM) is used by a function table?

Tags: oracle, memory, plsql

I'm thinking about implementing a function table. As the table could have around 100 000 result sets I wish to know the memory usage of it (on the RAM). Can I check (if possible) with toad or pl/sql developer how much memory is allocated for my result sets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"function table"* is an odd usage. Do you mean a PL/SQL collection or nested table? Or do you mean a pipelined function?

Comment: I mean PL/SQL collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your session PGA holds the data and thus you can query your session statistics to see how much is consumed, eg

```
SQL> select s.name, st.value
  2  from   v$statname s, v$mystat st
  3  where st.statistic# = s.statistic#
  4  and s.name like '%pga%';

NAME                                                                  VALUE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
session pga memory                                                  5025416
session pga memory max                                              5025416

SQL> declare
  2    type t is table of char(1000) index by pls_integer;
  3    r t;
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1 .. 10000
  6    loop
  7      r(i) := rpad('x',1000);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select s.name, st.value
  2  from   v$statname s, v$mystat st
  3  where st.statistic# = s.statistic#
  4  and s.name like '%pga%';

NAME                                                                  VALUE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
session pga memory                                                  4370056
session pga memory max                                             16297608
```